# Write Json Webhook to Cloud Firestore with Cloud Functions. Cloud Function Failed to Deploy. Function failed on loading user code

Tags: node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Webhook that delivers a complex JSON payload to my Cloud Function URL, and writes that JSON to collections & documents within my Cloud Firestore.

I believe the Node.JS Runtime on Google Cloud Functions uses the Express Middleware HTTP framework.

I have a WooCommerce Webhook that wants me to send a JSON to a URL, I believe this is a POST http request.

I've used Webhook.site to test the Webhook, and it is displaying the correct JSON payload.

Developers have suggested I use cloud functions to receive the JSON, parse the JSON and write it to the Cloud Firestore.

```js
// cloud-function-name = wooCommerceWebhook
exports.wooCommerceWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const payload = req.body;

    // Write to Firestore - People Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
        people_EmailWork: payload.billing.email,
    });

// Write to Firestore - Volociti Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("volociti").doc("fJHb1VBhzTbYmgilgTSh").collection("orders").doc("yzTBXvGja5KBZOEPKPtJ").collection("orders marketplace orders").doc().set({
        ordersintuit_CustomerIPAddress: payload.customer_ip_address,
    });

    // Write to Firestore - Companies Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("companies").doc().set({
        company_AddressMainStreet: payload.billing.address_1,
    });
    return res.status(200).end();
});
```

I have the logs to my cloud function's failure to deploy if that is helpful.

```
Function cannot be initialized. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
```

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`file? Also, do you get more details typing `firebase functions:log` via the CLI

Comment: I've added my package.json to the original post.

Comment: Is this the `package.json` file under the functions directory?? You should have at least find in this file   `"dependencies": {    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0", ...
  },`

Comment: This is the default package.json that is generated upon created a cloud function via the GCP UI. I can add those dependencies & give you an updated error messages, if one exists.

Comment: Aren't you using the Firebase CLI to deploy?

Comment: I am not using the Firebase CLI for this function. I am using GCP Cloud Function UI, Node.js 14 Runtime and the Inline Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correctly [define the dependency](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs) with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin?authuser=1) for Node.js, and initialize it, as shown below.

You also need to change the way you declare the function: `exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {...}` instead of `exports.wooCommerceWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {...});`. The one you used is for Cloud Functions deployed through the CLI.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2"  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();

exports.wooCommerceWebhook = async (req, res) => {  // SEE COMMENT BELOW
    const payload = req.body;

    // Write to Firestore - People Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("people").doc().set({
      people_EmailWork: payload.billing.email,
    });

    // Write to Firestore - Volociti Collection
    await admin.firestore().collection("volociti").doc("fJHb1VBhzTbYmgilgTSh").collection("orders").doc("yzTBXvGja5KBZOEPKPtJ").collection("orders marketplace orders").doc().set({
      ordersintuit_CustomerIPAddress: payload.customer_ip_address,
    });

   // Write to Firestore - Companies Collection
   await admin.firestore().collection("companies").doc().set({
       company_AddressMainStreet: payload.billing.address_1,
   });

   return res.status(200).end();
 };
```